Battle Royale-esque (japanese film) movie with tightrope crossing scene
Need some help to ID a film.
This is a film which I remember watching as a kid around 10-15 years ago. It is a film where players have to (are forced to?) complete game stages for some benefit which I forgot (money? chance of survival?).
One particular standout scene which I can remember is a scene where players have to cross from the top of one building to another by balancing on a single rope. Failure to balance will result in the characters falling to their deaths. In this scene, some of the characters fall due to the strong wind and lack of balance. In the end, one of the players reach the other building, and has to open a door or window to enter the building. As he does so, the difference in air pressure from inside and outside the building causes wind to blow out of the window/door, blowing him off the rope right at the end before he could enter the other building and clear the stage. Some of the players after him managed to enter the building and clear the stage.
This scene is what I remember from the movie. Hope it is useful for IDing the movie.

I just found it. It is Kaiji, a movie adapted from a comic series of the same name.
http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1309449/
Thanks guys.
